# How to repeat this code for all tabs? Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension that runs the following when I click a button on popup.html:

1. gets and reads the urls of each tab one by one
2. if the url starts with "https://www.linkedin.com/company/", gets the
   company ID right after "company/". (The url usually looks like this:
   https://www.linkedin.com/company/164233?trk=prof-exp-company-name so
   in this case for example, I would like to get "164233") Then it
   should create a new tab with the following url:
   https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=164233

The following codes successfully do what I want for the current tab only. I want the extension to do it for **all tabs** when I click 'btn2'.

How can I repeat it? With a for loop? Thanks!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
        document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', printurl)
});

printurl = function(){
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {


    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var query = tabs[0].url;
    var companyId = query.slice(33, 41);
    var companyId2 = companyId.replace( /\D/g, '');

    saeurl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search?pivotType=EMPLOYEE&pivotId=' + companyId2;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: saeurl, selected:false})

})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, you need to make a few changes. Firstly, if you want all tabs then you don't want to query for [`active`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) or [`lastFocusedWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Once you've fixed that issue you should get all tabs, at which point you need to complete your logic for each tab in `tabs`.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {

    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
        var query = tabs[i].url;
        var companyId = query.slice(33, 41);
        var companyId2 = companyId.replace( /\D/g, '');

        saeurl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search?pivotType=EMPLOYEE&pivotId=' + companyId2;
        chrome.tabs.create({url: saeurl, selected:false})
    }

})
```

It's also worth thinking about the logic you're using to extract the company ID from the URL. Your current logic relies on the length of the ID, which could change. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561) which shows a few different ways of parse URIs.